# Is it better to store uniform descriptors in a single buffer or use seperate buffers for each frame?

Tags: vulkan

My application has a max of 2 frames in flight. The vertex shader takes a uniform buffer containing matrices. Because 2 frames could potentially be rendering at the same time I believe I need to have separate memory for each frame's uniform buffer.

Is it preferable to create a single buffer than holds the uniforms of both frames and use an offset within the buffer to do updates. Or is it better that each frame have its own buffer?

Comment: Personally I use separate uniform buffers for each frame, but each frame's uniform buffer will contain the data for hundreds of separate draw calls across many different shaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can do either; it ultimately boils down to what makes the most sense implementation-wise. Provided you can ensure that you're not overwriting buffer data that's still active (and being consumed on the GPU), one memory allocation would be sufficient. It's a big advantage of the Vulkan API (since you have full control) but it does make life more complicated.

In my use-case, I use pages of allocations (kinda like a heap model) where I allocate on demand and return blocks when they're done (basically, if a reference is removed, I age out for however many frames of buffering I have and then free the block). This is targeted at uniform buffers that change infrequently.

For per-draw uniform data, I use push constants - this might be worth looking at for your use-case. Since the per-instance matrix is "use once then discard" and is relatively small, this actually makes life simpler, and could even have a performance benefit, to boot.

Comment: Yes I'm not entirely certain where to draw the line between uniforms & push constants. But I was thinking that something that changes once per frame like a view/proj matrix might go in the uniform and something that changes more frequently like a model's world transform matrix might go in a push constant.

Comment: That sounds like the right kind of delineation. Once-per-frame (or per view) data in a regular uniform buffer, and per-instance "throw-away" data as push constants.